# How to change from request.site to Site._find_for_request(request) in wagtail 2.9

Tags: django, wagtail

I've recently upgraded my wagtail app to the latest version, version 2.9, now since the wagtail site middleware has been deprecated I'm having trouble getting my site to work. I was using a request.site now  wagtail 2.9 uses Site._find_for_request(request)

How do I change my current code to work with the latest wagtail version? Thanks in advance

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
```

def og_image(context, page):

```
protocol = re.compile(r'^(\w[\w\.\-\+]*:)*//')

if protocol.match(settings.MEDIA_URL):
    base_url = ''
else:
    base_url = context['request'].site.root_url

if page:
    if page.og_image:
        return base_url + page.og_image.get_rendition('original').url
    elif page.cover_image:
        return base_url + page.cover_image.get_rendition('original').url
if LayoutSettings.for_site(context['request'].site).logo:
    layout_settings = LayoutSettings.for_site(context['request'].site)
    return base_url + layout_settings.logo.get_rendition('original').url
return None
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like that you're still doing the old way of getting current site, in this case:

```
context['request'].site
```

where `context['request']` is the request object. Change those occurrences to below as recommended in the [Wagtail 2.9 release notes](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.9/releases/2.9.html#sitemiddleware-and-request-site-deprecated):

```
Site.find_for_request(context['request'])
```

Don't forget to make sure that you have `from wagtail.core.models import Site` somewhere on top of the file or else your code won't work, i.e. you get an error.

You can find more info on `Site.find_for_request` in the [docs](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.9/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Site.find_for_request).

Comment: Sorry for taking long to reply, Thanks a lot the solution worked

Comment: You're most certainly welcome. Don't forget to mark this answer as the solution (it's the checkmark below the arrows on the left side) so that future Wagtail developers can refer to this should they need help on this topic.